# javafx: How to monitor state change of a variable that has more than 2 states?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a variable `money` of type `double`. I want this variable to have 3 states like this:

```
double money = something;

public int getMoneyState(){
       if (money > 0){
          return 1; 
       } else if(money == 0){
          return 0;
       } else{
          return -1;
       }
}
```

Problem is: I only know how to formulate this problem in the most conventional way, that is without using any javafx libraries / functions.

Eventually, I want to have a tableView where one of the columns will display the `money` variable, and its font color will change depending on the state of this variable, i.e. if after editing the cell, `money = 100`, the state will be `1` and font color is yellow. If after editing the cell, `money = 0`, the state will be `0` and font color is grey.And if after editing the cell, `money = -555`, the state will be `-1` and font color is Green.

**What I am looking for:** I want to be able to **track** the money variable as well as its state and any changes in state. By that, I mean a change in the money variable will lead to a change in the state by using a method similar to `getMoneyState()` above. And depending on the state of the variable, the cell's font color will change.

I need help re-writing getMoneyState() method such that the state will automatically be updated after the user edits the `money` cell.

Hope this makes more sense.

Comment: What do you mean? JavaFX is "standard Java code". Just use the code you have posted.

Comment: Sorry @James_D, I meant I do not know how to use solve my problem using `properties` or `bindings`. That's why i only posted what I have written down so far. Please do not downvote this question, as I am working on presenting a problem in a better way. And English is not my first language. I am working hard to phrase my questions in a way that it can be understood by audience.

Comment: Please update the question so it is clearer; I will remove the downvote once it makes sense.

Comment: @James_D, let me know if the question is still unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have `money` represented as a `DoubleProperty`:

```
DoubleProperty money = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
```

for example, you can do

```
IntegerBinding moneyState = Bindings.createIntegerBinding(() -> {
    if (money.get() > 0) {
        return 1 ;
    } else if (money.get() == 0) {
        return 0 ;
    } else {
        return -1 ;
    }
}, money);
```

The two arguments to [`createIntegerBinding`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#createIntegerBinding-java.util.concurrent.Callable-javafx.beans.Observable...-) are a function returning an `Integer`, and a list of other observables on which the binding depends (here there is only one, `money`).

Now you can add listeners to `moneyState` or bind to it in the usual way.

If `money` is a property in some bean, then you can expose `moneyState` as a `ReadOnlyIntegerProperty` in a similar way:

```
public class MyEntity {

    private final DoubleProperty money = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    public DoubleProperty moneyProperty() {
        return money ;
    }
    public final double getMoney() {
        return moneyProperty().get();
    }
    public final void setMoney(double money) {
        moneyProperty().set(money);
    }

    private final ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper moneyState = new ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper();

    public ReadOnlyIntegerProperty moneyStateProperty() {
        return moneyState.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }
    public int getMoneyState() {
        return moneyStateProperty().get();
    }

    private IntegerBinding moneyStateBinding ;

    public MyEntity(double money) {
        setMoney(money) ;
        moneyStateBinding = Bindings.createIntegerBinding(() -> {
            if (getMoney() > 0) {
                return 1 ;
            } else if (getMoney() == 0) {
                return 0 ;
            } else {
                return -1 ;
            }
        }, moneyProperty());

        moneyState.bind(moneyStateBinding);
    }
}
```

A couple of other options. First note that your logic is already implemented by [`Math.signum()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#signum-double-), so you can do:

```
IntegerBinding moneyState = Bindings.createIntegerBinding(() -> 
    (int) Math.signum(money.get()), money);
```

You can also implement it with the fluent Bindings API:

```
IntegerBinding moneyState = Bindings.when(money.greaterThan(0)).then(1)
    .otherwise(Bindings.when(money.isEqualTo(0)).then(0).otherwise(-1));
```

Comment: Hi @James_D, since I will be extracting this `moneyState` variable from the object, when I pass it as a parameter into a class , which is mainly written for defining `setRowFactory`, in this case would I be passing  `Function<T, IntegerExpression>` ? Does my question make sense to you ?

Comment: I don't really understand that, but I updated the question to show how to incorporate this into a JavaFX-style bean.

Comment: I mean in my code, I will have to extract the `moneyState` variable from the `MyEntity` object.To achieve I will be doing  something like `MyEntity::moneyState` . So my question is : is moneyState an `IntegerExpression` ?Thanks a lot for your great answer by the way.,

Comment: In the updated version, `moneyStateProperty()` returns a [`ReadOnlyIntegerProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/ReadOnlyIntegerProperty.html), which is an `IntegerExpression` (among other things). So `MyEntity::moneyStateProperty` could be assigned to a `Function<MyEntity, IntegerExpression>` (for example).

Answer (score 0):

You could create and `Observer` and make a `MoneyClass`, which inherits the `Observable` Class for example. You could then track any changes to the Money and it´s state made

The result could be looking like this

```
// Money class
import java.util.Observable;

public class MoneyClass extends Observable{

    private double money = 0;
    private int state = 0;

    public static final int POSITIV = 1;
    public static final int ZERO = 0;
    public static final int NEGATIV = -1;

    public int getMoneyState(){
           if (money > 0){
              return MoneyClass.POSITIV; 
           } else if(money == 0){
              return MoneyClass.ZERO;
           } else{
              return MoneyClass.NEGATIV;
           }
    }

    public void setMoney(int money) {
        this.money = money;
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers("Money");
        setMoneyState();
    }

    public double getMoney() {
        return money;
    }

    public int getState() {
        return state;
    }

    private void setMoneyState() {
        if (state != getMoneyState()) {
            state = getMoneyState();
            setChanged();
            notifyObservers("State");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
//Observer
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

public class MoneyObserver implements Observer{

    public void addObserving(MoneyClass money) {
        money.addObserver(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        if(arg instanceof String) {
            String type = (String) arg;
            if(type.equals("Money")) {
                System.out.println("Money got changed to " + ((MoneyClass)o).getMoney());
            } else if(type.equals("State")) {
                System.out.println("State got changed to " + ((MoneyClass)o).getState());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MoneyObserver o = new MoneyObserver();
        MoneyClass c = new MoneyClass();
        o.addObserving(c);
        c.setMoney(20);
        c.setMoney(50);
        c.setMoney(-30);
    }

}
```